# PHP array key and value

Tags: php

I have a simple question.

I've created a small test array with discount codes and their discounts.
However, when I run the foreach, variable `$code` is `0`, and everything is placed in `$discount` . I don't see my error in notation for accessing the key and value of the array?

```
  private function _handleDiscount() {
    $discountCodes = array(["AZERTYUIOP" => 8.00, "QSDFGHJKLM" => 10.00]);
    $_SESSION['cart']['total'] = $_POST['totalValue'];
    foreach($discountCodes as $code => $discount){
      if($_POST['discountCode'] === $code){
        $_POST['totalValue'] - $discount;
        $_SESSION['cart']['total'] = $_POST['totalValue'];
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Should you be doing something with the value in `$_POST['totalValue'] - $discount;`?

Comment: `array(["AZERTYUIOP" => 8.00, "QSDFGHJKLM" => 10.00]);` is creating two arrays, it should be `array("AZERTYUIOP" => 8.00, "QSDFGHJKLM" => 10.00);`

Comment: Ah, thanks for that! I probably read the documentation wrong.

Comment: You probably want to do `$_SESSION['cart']['total'] = $_POST['totalValue'] - $discount;` or `$_POST['totalValue'] = $_POST['totalValue'] - $discount;`

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
$_POST['totalValue'] - $discount;
```

with

```
$_POST['totalValue'] -= $discount;
```

and replace

```
$discountCodes = array(["AZERTYUIOP" => 8.00, "QSDFGHJKLM" => 10.00]);
```

with

```
$discountCodes = array("AZERTYUIOP" => 8.00, "QSDFGHJKLM" => 10.00);
```

Comment: It's always helpful to explain _why_ something should be changed, even if it's not a major change.